# How do i change table/grid view to tile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have one html code, I want to change its view (from table view to tile view) using jquery.
I use jquery "addclass" and "removeclass" method, I also try "wrap" and "unwrap" method for change classes.

Here is my code.

**HTML (Link button click)**

```
<a href="#" id="button"> <img src="images/icon_roleview3.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icon_roleview3_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icon_roleview3.png'"></a>
```

**HTML (Table code)**

```
<div class="rolesboxstart">
    <div class="overflowscroll">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tablestyle" style="overflow-x: scroll;" id = "tablestyle">
      <tr id = "tabletr">
        <td width="22%" class="tableviewtop">title1</td>
        <td width="12%" class="tableviewtop textaligncenter">title2</td>
        <td width="14%" class="tableviewtop textaligncenter">title3</td>
        <td width="6%" class="tableviewtop textaligncenter">title4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#"">data1</a></td>
        <td class="textaligncenter">data2</td>
        <td class="textaligncenter">data3</td>
        <td class="textaligncenter">data4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#"">data1</a></td>
        <td class="textaligncenter">data2</td>
        <td class="textaligncenter">data3</td>
        <td class="textaligncenter">data4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output** (Table / Grid View)

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
| **title1** | **title2** | **title3** | **title4** |
 ---------------------------------------------------
|   data1    |    data2   |     data3  |     data4  |
 ---------------------------------------------------
|   data1    |    data2   |     data3  |     data4  |
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

**Jquery Code (for add and remove class)**

```
$(function() {
     $( "#button" ).click(function() {
        $("#tablestyle").removeClass("tablestyle tableviewtop textaligncenter");
        document.getElementById('tabletr').style.display='none'; // hide table data
        $("#tablestyle").addClass("rolesbox");
        $(".textaligncenter").addClass("title");
        $("#tabletr").addClass("content");
        /*console.log("unwrap classes");
        $('table').contents().unwrap();// remove (unwrap) talbe view classes
        console.log("wrap new classes");
        $('.tableviewtop').wrap('<div class="title" />');
        console.log("done");
        return false;*/
    });
});
```

**I want it in tile view**

```
   __________             ___________          ______________
  |          |           |           |        |              |
  |          |           |           |        |              |
  |__________|           |___________|        |______________|
```

**JS Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/tutorialdrive/Xxqq5/

Comment: So what exactly is the problem now ?

Comment: using this jquery i'm able to add and remove classes from table, but can't change its view using adding tile view classes.

Comment: what do you mean by tile view??

Comment: Where is your `css`? And what is the need of adding class in line `$("#tabletr").addClass("content");`, if its `display` is `none`?

Comment: @ShivamPandya: I guess you should check the CSS class which can transform your table view to tile view .` .tile {
         display: block;
         float: left;
         margin: 7.5px;
         background: #B50000;
      }
`

Comment: Meanwhile simulate the same on jsfiddle, it will be easy to fix your issue

Comment: @dreamweiver ok, i put code in jsfiddle,

Comment: Here is jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/tutorialdrive/Xxqq5/

Comment: @dreamweiver link added.

Comment: @ShivamPandya:is this what you wanted ? http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/Xxqq5/2/

Comment: @dreamweiver yes, but i want, two row in two different boxes. [box1] [box2]. side by side.

Comment: @ShivamPandya:hey bro can u try this http://jsfiddle.net/wtyxd/3/

Comment: yes, but number 2 and 3 are all readily in column structure, my code are in row and i want to remove them.
Is there any jquery for row to column ?

Comment: @ShivamPandya : I hope this is what you wanted :) http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/Xxqq5/14/

Comment: Exactly this one, thanks for help, you can answer that script here. I give you and accepted answer,
thanks once again @dreamweiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS:**

```
.tiled { float: left; margin: 7.5px; background: #B50000; }
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
     $( "#button" ).click(function() {
        $("#tablestyle").removeClass("tablestyle tableviewtop textaligncenter");
        document.getElementById('tabletr').style.display='none';
        $("#tablestyle").addClass("rolesbox");
        //$(".textaligncenter").addClass("title");
         $(".tile td").addClass("title");
         $(".tile").addClass("tiled");
        $("#tabletr").addClass("content");

    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:**

[Working code](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/Xxqq5/14/)